# How to get Google Sheets sidebar input to server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a dialog to show and edit document properties in a sidebar of Google Spreadsheets.

I managed to show the property values in the sidebar and even create text input fields to interact with via the sidebar. But finally I'm not able to get the values back into the server-side script using a serverHandler.

How are interactive dialogs with a sidebar are supported in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say, but it sounds like you're using UiApp for your sidebar.

A serverHandler will receive the value of the element that the handler was attached to. For instance:

```
var button = uiInstance.createSubmitButton("Submit");
var servHandler = uiInstance.createServerHandler("myServerHandler");
button.addClickHandler(servHandler);
```

When `myServerHandler()` gets invoked due to a button press, it will receive the value of `button` in the event object.

```
{"parameter":
  {"clientY":"13",
   "clientX":"40",
   "eventType":"click",    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   "ctrl":"false",
   "meta":"false",
   "source":"u503258948978",
   "button":"1",           <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   "alt":"false",
   "screenY":"207",
   "screenX":"1020",
   "shift":"false",
   "y":"13",
   "x":"40"}
}
```

To pass other values to the serverHandler, use `addCallbackElement()` to attach them to the handler.

```
var clientInput = uiInstance.createTextBox().setName("client-input");
...
servHandler.addCallbackElement(clientInput);
```

Now we will also received the input of the text box `clientInput`, as an attribute named `parameter["client-input"]`.

```
{"parameter":
  {"clientY":"13",
   "clientX":"40",
   "eventType":"click",
   "ctrl":"false",
   "client-input":"hello",    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   "meta":"false",
   "source":"u503258948978",
   "button":"1",
   "alt":"false",
   "screenY":"207",
   "screenX":"1020",
   "shift":"false",
   "y":"13",
   "x":"40"}
}
```

#### Example

This simple example of a spreadsheet-contained script gets one piece of input from the user, passes it to a serverHandler, which then updates the sidebar to display a computational result.

[image: screenshot]

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Display a sidebar with a button, an input box, and a
 * label. The label is initially hidden.
 */
function showSidebar() {
  var uiInstance = UiApp.createApplication()
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);

  // Create the widgets to be used on sidebar
  var clientInput = uiInstance.createTextBox().setName("client-input");
  var serverOutput = uiInstance.createLabel().setId("server-response").setVisible(false);
  var button = uiInstance.createSubmitButton("Submit");

  // Set up server handler, add callbackElement(s), and attach to button
  var servHandler = uiInstance.createServerHandler("myServerHandler");
  servHandler.addCallbackElement(clientInput);
  button.addClickHandler(servHandler);

  // Place our widgets on the sidebar
  uiInstance.add(button).add(clientInput).add(serverOutput);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(uiInstance);
}

/**
 * Server handler - get the value of "client-input",
 * convert it to upper case, then display in the
 * Label in the UI.
 */
function myServerHandler(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e, undefined, 2)); // Log the event object
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var text = e.parameter["client-input"];
  var upperText = text.toUpperCase();
  app.getElementById("server-response").setVisible(true).setText(upperText);
  return(app);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code worked fine and is a good starting point to further explore what is possible using the sidebar.
What I further want to do is:
- put code into a .lib file so I can use it in both Spreadsheet and docs
-use HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile

Comment: By the way: 
I raised my initial questions because I tried to use a sidebar translation function I had found at http://blog.pepf.nl/2013/08/add-a-translate-sidebar-to-your-google-drive-documents/, which worked with a docs sidebar (DocumentApp), but not with a spreadsheet sidebar (SpreadsheetApp).